# How do I run stonesense

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to get Stonesense working for the latest Dwarf Fortress.

I am using the latest LNP pack [(40.16 r2)](http://dffd.wimbli.com/file.php?id=7622).

Stonesense does not come with this package anymore for "technical reasons" as you can read on the bay12 forums.

I have Stonesense downloaded from their github [here](https://github.com/DFHack/stonesense), but I can't find any where that tells me where to put these files in order to get them working!

Comment: Might those "technical reasons" be simply "it doesn't work anymore with the most recent version"?

Comment: Thankfully, no. I'd imagine it's because the pack to seems to work on both Linux and Windows. stonesense used to be an exe. which obviously is for Windows and wouldn't work on Linux.

Comment: Your title no longer matches your question; you want to know where to put the files, not how to run it.

Comment: Sorry Frank, thanks for editing it but I'm leaving the title as is because it may not be down to where to put the files. It might require browsing to the directory using the dfhack console for example. I don't miss any potential answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the result of outdated documentation and a timely bug.

First, Stonesense is now included with DFHack in the Starter Pack (previously known as the `LNP`). However from around versions 40.14-40.19 stonesense was broken due to changes in DF proper, so it wasn't shipped.

Updating to the latest DFHack / Starter Pack (for DF v0.40.19) will include stonesense.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for answering :) been waiting ages to have a go with stonesense adventure mode